# new Date().getTime() not returning timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: java, unix-timestamp, java.util.date, gettime

I've a class which is using `java.util.Date` class to create a date object and using `getTime()` to get current milliseconds.

I've seen in the Java documentation that `getTime()` returns the milliseconds, and the same case is on my machine.

I've one other server, when I am deploying my application on server, the same `getTime()` returns the timestamp in seconds.

e.g.

- value on server: 1350054625
- value on local: 1350054625000

I am wondering how this is possible, I tried the same code locally and again I got timestamp in milliseconds.

Below is the part of code...

```
String longTime = new Long((new Date().getTime())).toString();
if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug("LAST_FEED_TIME will be " + longTime + " stored.");
```

Comment: How are you getting the value from the server?

Comment: Date is a wrapper for the value you get from `System.currentTimeMillis();` can you try using that instead?

Comment: And what JRE version on server?

Comment: @PeterLawrey : yes i've tried the same, it's working fine for me but i am looking in the direction that why the getTime() method is behaving like this.

Comment: I would say that string in logs files is trimmed somehow or you missed something. I don't think that there could be JVM/OS issue

Comment: Are you sure you not removing trailing zeros?

Comment: @user1516873 : i don't know the configuration. i just have access to a directory where i am uploading my files via ftp, i know 1 thing that it's unix server and locally i am running on windows.

Comment: @Anton : I've not done anything with the value while logging

Comment: OS should not be relevant here. Try to implement simple command line app that prints `new Date().getTime()` and run it on your server with the same JVM

Comment: If the `System.currentTimeMillis()` is correct but the Date is wrong then the value used to construct the Date was also incorrect.  I.e. the bug is not in Date but how it was constructed.

Comment: Post the **exact code** you use to show the value.

Comment: You are going through quite a number of redundant steps in there, but I don't see the reason for your obsevered behavior.

Comment: Try `String longTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : yes, System.currentTimeMillis() is working fine for me but i am looking in the direction that why the getTime() method is behaving like this.

Comment: If you are positive that replacing with the code I posted changes the behavior on the server, then the only option I can see is that you are sucking in a broken implementation of `java.util.Date` at the server. This boils down to the server-side JRE or, theoretically but not very likely, to another JAR on the classpath that (should I say maliciously?) defines a broken `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 9):

'new Date()' in turn uses System.currentTimeMillis()

> **System.currentTimeMillis**
>
> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds.
>
> See the description of the class Date for a discussion of slight
>   discrepancies that may arise between "computer time" and coordinated
>   universal time (UTC).

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: This doesn't quite explain why the same code would return different results when run on different machines, does it?

Comment: Yes, This doesn't answer the question. But I thought this information would help in finding the issue. Ex : "Some operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds."
The unit of time measurement as per OS in the server can be second.

Comment: That's true - but then Java should return it in the same format, but the milliseconds set to '0'.  I understand why you placed the information, I was just checking to see if I'm missing something :)

Comment: I've changed code to System.currentTimeMillis() and my problem is solved, still i am looking for solution to this case, or an exact reason for why api is behaving in this way...